# How to define group of flags in go?

Tags: go

I'm trying to make use of the [flag](http://golang.org/pkg/flag/) package. My whole issue is that I need to specify groups/multiple values for the same parameter.
  For example I need to parse a command as below:

```
 go run mycli.go -action first -point 10 -action
 second -point 2 -action 3rd -point something
```

I need to retrieve each group of action/point param. Is it possible?

Comment: No. That's something the `flag` package does not support.

Comment: I guess I have to encode somehow everything in a single param/string.

Comment: Nope, not supported. Perhaps one of the [third party flag packages](http://godoc.org/?q=flags) support the feature.

Comment: @AnthonyHat What you want is just not how ordinary options work. You might want to implement your own option parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flag package won't help you. Closest you'll get is the os package:

```
[jadekler@Jeans-MacBook-Pro:~/go/src]$ go run temp.go asdasd lkjasd -boom bam -hello world -boom kablam

[/var/folders/15/r6j3mdp97p5247bkkj94p4v00000gn/T/go-build548488797/command-line-arguments/_obj/exe/temp asdasd lkjasd -boom bam -hello world -boom kablam]
```

So, the first runtime flag key would be os.Args[1], the value would be os.Args[2], the next key would be os.Args[3], and so on.

Comment: yeah, I thought about that, though I was not sure the order is preserved. Anyway in the end I've decided to encode the whole thing in a string separated by &&

Answer (score 1):

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

// Define a type named "intslice" as a slice of ints
type intslice []int

// Now, for our new type, implement the two methods of
// the flag.Value interface...
// The first method is String() string
func (i *intslice) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d", *i)
}

// The second method is Set(value string) error
func (i *intslice) Set(value string) error {
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", value)
    tmp, err := strconv.Atoi(value)
    if err != nil {
        *i = append(*i, -1)
    } else {
        *i = append(*i, tmp)
    }
    return nil
}

var myints intslice

func main() {
    flag.Var(&myints, "i", "List of integers")
    flag.Parse()
}
```

Ref: http://lawlessguy.wordpress.com/2013/07/23/filling-a-slice-using-command-line-flags-in-go-golang/